# Obtaining width and height of the plane detected in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

```
func getSizeOfModel(_ node: SCNNode){

   let (min, max) = node.boundingBox
  
   let widthOfNode = max.x - min.x
   let heightOfNode = max.y - min.y
   
   print("
        Width Of Node = \(widthOfNode)
        Height Of Node = \(heightOfNode)
    ")
```

Does adding it to the code of Tracking & visualizing planes to the viewcontroller.swift serve my purpose?

Comment: You can see a full version of how to use `extent` and `center` parameters of `ARPlaneAnchor` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063069/how-to-calculate-quadrangle-for-visible-part-of-vertical-plane/65064966#65064966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `ARPlaneAnchor.extent`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneanchor/2882055-extent